# How to show $M$ a 2-manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Let $f$ be a continuous differentiable function on an open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$
. Let $M :=\{(x, y, f(x, y)) : (x, y)\in A\}$
Show that M is a 2-manifold. 
Attempts: I know the definition of manifold, but in this question i don't know how to show the existence of function $\Phi(x)=0$ for all $x\in M$ for any neighborhood of $x\in M$.

Comment: Consider the projection to the first two coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is open therefore is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$. You show that $M$ is homeomorphic to $A$ by $h: M \to A$, $(x,y,f(x,y)) \mapsto (x,y)$. The map $h$ is surjective and as it is invertible it is also injective. Since $f$ is continuous, $h$ is continuous. Remains to be shown that it is open.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
\Phi(x,y,z) = z-f(x,y)
$$
and notice that $\nabla \Phi \neq 0$ since $\partial \Phi/\partial z = 1$.